# Unable to update an Individual Searchbox with popup modal in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have an application in React/Typescript where we have dynamic generation of rows. Every row has a Searchbox and within that Searchbox, there is a button that adds the popup. In that popup, there is a Textfield, which after being populated, has to pass its value to the Searchbox from which the popup was opened.

```
 {idx == 0 && <div className="bold">Organization Contact Name</div>}
<div className="buttonIn"> 
     <Searchbox  searchTitle={this.state.contactName}
        suggestionCallback={this.entitySelectHandler}
        styles={searchBoxStylesWithButton}/>                                                
        <IconButton iconProps={addIcon} className="insideSearchBoxButton"
         onClick={this._isModalOpen}/>
</div>                                                
                                        
   </> }


  </td>
  <td>
    {idx > 0 && <IconButton iconProps={deleteIcon}
                      className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                      onClick={this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}
                      />}
   </td>                                  
    </tr> ))}
    </table>
   {this.state.showHideContactNameAndURL &&
      <PrimaryButton className="newpartnerbutton propposition"
           text="New Contact"
           iconProps={addIcon}
           allowDisabledFocus
           disabled={false}
           checked={true}
           styles={buttonCreateNewStyles}
            onClick={this.handleAddRow}
      />                          
    }

        <Modal
            titleAriaId={`ExternalPartner123`}
            isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
            isBlocking={true}
            containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
            className="modelPopup"
            dragOptions={dragOptions}
        >
            <div className={contentStyles.body}>
                <Stack horizontal tokens={stackTokens} styles={stackStyles}>
                    <Stack {...columnProps}>                                
                         <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="left">
                                <p className="bold">Contact Information</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <IconButton className="right"
                                    styles={iconButtonStyles}
                                    iconProps={cancelIcon}
                                    ariaLabel="Close Modal"
                                    onClick={this._isModalOpen}
                                />                                    
                                </td>                                
                            </tr>
                        </table>                                 
                       
                        <TextField placeholder="First Name" onChange={this._changeContactFirstName} />
                        <TextField placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this._changeContactLastName} />
                        <TextField placeholder="Title" />
                        <TextField placeholder="Organization Name" />
                        <TextField placeholder="Phone Number" />
                        <TextField placeholder="Fax Number" />
                        <TextField placeholder="Email Address" />
                        <Stack horizontal tokens={stackTokens}>
                          <PrimaryButton text="Save Contact" allowDisabledFocus disabled={false} 
                                   checked={true} className="savecontinuebutton" onClick={this._setContact}/>
                          <PrimaryButton text="Cancel Contact Query" onClick={this._isModalOpen} allowDisabledFocus disabled={false} 
                                   checked={true} className="cancelbutton" />
                        </Stack>                                
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>                        
            </div>
        </Modal>

private _isModalOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let isOpen = this.state.isModalOpen;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isModalOpen: !prevState.isModalOpen
    }));
}
private _setContact = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let isOpen = this.state.isModalOpen;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
         contactName: this.state.contactFirstName + " " +  this.state.contactLastName
     }));

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isModalOpen: !prevState.isModalOpen
    }));

private handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      name: "",
      mobile: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };
```

So, this code works the following way. We initially have a row
[image]

Then we add another row by clicking the "New Contact"

[image]

Then, we click the plus button to open the popup. On that popup we fill out the first two top text fields. And when we click the 'Save Contact' button, the popup will close and the values from the first two top text fields on the popup populate the search box from which the popup was open
[image]

In other words, something that can be done in classic JS in a fraction of a second, in React/Typescript seems to be very challenging

Is there a way to generate a state dynamically, or is there a way to access the Searchbox by ID in React/Typescript?

The way I currently have the code, after the 'Save Contact', ALL Searchboxes get updated, not the specific ONE.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest passing the index of the search bar into the function that opens the modal so you know which modal to refer back to when you click submit in the form.

You are doing something similar with the delete button

```
onClick={this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}
```

On that note, this looks like it might be an issue, as you're passing the result of handleRemoveSpecificRow() through to onClick, not the function itself.  You'll want to wrap this in a lambda:

```
onClick={() => this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}
```

Back to the original question:

```
      <PrimaryButton className="newpartnerbutton propposition"
           text="New Contact"
           iconProps={addIcon}
           allowDisabledFocus
           disabled={false}
           checked={true}
           styles={buttonCreateNewStyles}
           onClick={() => this.handleAddRow(idx)}
      />
```

This should give you the information you need in the scope you need it.

If you had provided the handle functions I could've gone further down the rabit hole with you.

Edit:

Sorry, I got confused because I read _isModalOpen and thought it was just going to answer the question of if the modal was open and not toggle the modal open.  This is where you're going to want to pass the index into:

```
<IconButton iconProps={addIcon} className="insideSearchBoxButton" onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => this._isModalOpen(event, idx)}/>
```

Then store it in a state variable

```
private _isModalOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, currentIndex: number): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let isOpen = this.state.isModalOpen;
    this.setState({currentIndex});
```

You're also going to want to change the structure in the state that stores the name to be a list of names instead of a singular name; so:

```
    let contacts = this.state.contacts.slice(); // create a copy of the state contacts
    contacts[this.state.currentIndex] = {firstName: "", lastName: ""} // Populate these from modal 
    this.setState({contacts});
```

To put it mildly, you have your code all setup so that there's a single search bar, and the structure in the state supports that.  You need to alter the structures to hold multiple sets of data.

Or you could move the state inside of the search bar component.  That way, you'd have a separate state for every search bar; just accessing the data within the search bar would be more challenging from the parent scope.

Honestly, I'm confused from a UI perspective why you're duplicating the search bar in the first place.  It'd make sense to just have one of these at the top, and when you use the search bar and submit the modal, have it clear the search bar and then add the users in a list below the search bar.

Comment: I just added to the question body the handleAddRow method. Please let me know if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to update all of the search boxes you could create a state in form of an array which stores all data needed for search box as an object.

Once you click the "Save Contact" button you could target the wanted search box with its index (when you map out the search boxes) and update only that object inside the array.

Just a quick example that might help in how to get to it:

```
const [searchBoxes, setSearchBoxes] = useState([])

handleCreateSearchBox = (params) => {
   setSearchBoxes( prevState => ([
     ...prevState, {title: params.title}
 ]));
}
```

the example above is the most simple way you could "push" new searchBox object into array state so you could later target which searchBox to update based on the index when using the map function on render/return.

```
return (
  <>
    {searchBoxes.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        {'Your search box component'}
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

now you can create a handleOnClick that you can pass on the index of the search box and use it to update the searchBoxes state.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. One of my colleagues did suggest it but I found no examples of similar implementation. Is there any resource you could recommend I could follow? Thank you again!

I am just a little bit confused on that solution. Do I generate an element of a state collection dynamically when I add the row?